# Como posso obter o texto dentro de uma combobox?

Tags: php, combobox

Como posso obter o texto dentro da combobox para adicionar no banco de dados?

Por exemplo, "AC" ou "AL".

```
<select>
    <option value="1">AC</option>
    <option value="2">AL</option>
    ...
</select>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeEVK.png

Comment: Você precisa detalhar mais sua pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize jQuery e envie seus dados pro banco com Ajax:

```
$('select[name="combobox"]').change(function(){

   var text = $('select[name="combobox"] option:selected').text();

   $.ajax({
      url: "savar-no-bd.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {texto: text},
      success: function(data){
         console.log(data);
      }
   }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar jQuery.

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        var that=$(this).children('option:selected');
        alert(that.text());
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select name="combobox">
    <option value="1" class="option">Combobox Text</option>
    <option value="2" class="option">Combobox Text 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada. http://jsfiddle.net/5828u2bs/